# Woocommerce custom checkout field conditional discount

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've made a custom field for checkout in woocommerce:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', 'my_custom_checkout_field' );
function my_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {
    woocommerce_form_field( 'forhandler-kode', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
        'label'         => __('Har du fået en kode fra en butik? Skriv den her! (IKKE kuponkode)'),
        'placeholder'   => __('Indtast din kode'),
        'required'      => false,
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'forhandler-kode' ));
}
```

And now I'm trying to give the users a discount if they put in a specific code. While testing how to grab the field, I can't even make this happen even if just checking whether or not the field is full, using the following code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','woocommerce_custom_surcharge' );
function woocommerce_custom_surcharge() {
  global $woocommerce;

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( $_POST['forhandler-kode'] ) {
    $percentage = -0.1;
    $surcharge = ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total + $woocommerce->cart->shipping_total ) * $percentage;    
    $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Forhandlerkode Rabat', $surcharge, true, '' );
    }

}
```

I've tested without the if statement, and the code itself works fine. My problem simply put: I can't grab and check the value of my custom field. var_dump($_POST['forhandler-kode']); returns NULL

To clarify, I know I can use coupons, however, my employer needs it like this.

Comment: This can't work without javascript / ajax, as it's a live event on client side. so it's something much more complicated.

Comment: Well that sucks to know, as my ajax knowledge is basically none. Thanks for letting me know though, I'll have to come up with an alternative then.

Comment: There is a lot of related question/answers in StackOverFlow around Ajax with WordPress/WooCommerce. You are going to find out…